# LessCss - correct syntax for matching selector

Tags: css, less

I have the following code that I use main as an extend function

```
.clear-left
{
    > li:first-child {
        border-left:none;
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left:0;
    }
}

#footer ul
{
    &:extend(.clear-left);
}
```

I have been looking at how to make it more robust - much as you would within CSS.

In my CSS view, more robust selectors would be:

```
ul.clear-left
```

or using more Less

```
.inline-list.clear-left

    .inline-list
    {
        > li {
            float:left;
        }

        &:extend(.clearfix all);

    }
```

However, the selector compiles to:

```
ul#footer ul > li {
   // code here
}
```

Is what I'm describing achievable?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what CSS result you're going to get and what Less code you're trying to use to get that with actually (`.inline-list....clearfix` snippet looks confusing since it barely has any connection to `ul...clear-left`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the common code chunk named `.clear-left` wherever similar property settings are required and also append `.clear-left` to the selector while  extending (to make it more specific or robust), you can use either one of the following options (first is most preferred, last is least).

**Option 1:** Just append the required class to the parent selector at the time of extending. Here no additional changes is required to the common function. This is the simplest solution and the one that I would recommend personally.

```css
.clear-left {
    > li:first-child {
        border-left:none;
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left:0;
    }
}
#footer ul {
    &.clear-left:extend(.clear-left all){}; /* appended class while extending */
}
```

---

**Option 2:** Same as above but instead of making it as mixin with parentheses, just wrap it as part of wrapper selector like below. Here since it is not exactly a mixin that is used as a function, it can be extended and the selectors would be grouped to avoid repetitions. This approach is better than the next one but it would produce one extra selector line in the output.

```css
.some-wrapper{
    &.clear-left{
       > li:first-child {
            border-left:none;
            margin-left:0;
            padding-left:0;
        }
    }
}
#footer ul:extend(.some-wrapper all){}; /* extend attached to the selector */

#header ul:extend(.some-wrapper all){};
```

**Compiled Output:**

```css
.some-wrapper.clear-left > li:first-child, /* this is the extra selector */
#footer ul.clear-left > li:first-child,
#header ul.clear-left > li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

---

**Option 3:** Put the entire common function within a wrapper mixin, prefixwith the parent selector (`&`) and invoke it wherever required. Since the `.clear-left` is appended to the parent selector, in the output it would always be appended to the root parent selector within which it was invoked (like `.inline-list.clear-left` for this example). The disadvantage with this method is that mixins can be invoked/called but cannot be extended (meaning selectors would not be grouped and properties would be repeated again and again).

```css
.some-wrapper() {
    &.clear-left{ /* note the use of parent selector (&) */
       > li:first-child {
            border-left:none;
            margin-left:0;
            padding-left:0;
        }
    }
}

.inline-list {
    > li {
        float:left;
    }
    .some-wrapper; /* invoke the mixin */
}
```